# Real range of long range transceptor LORA RA-02 SX1278 with Arduino UNO

Tags: arduino-uno, communication

I'm working in a project where I have to send data from long distances (about 1 km) between 2 Arduinos UNO which are powered by computer's USB ports. The place is a small city with no large buildings. I have bought two transceptors [LORA RA-02 SX1278](https://docs.ai-thinker.com/_media/lora/docs/c048ps01a1_ra-02_product_specification_v1.1.pdf) at 433 MHz with an antenna for this frequency, like this:

[image]

The results are dissapointing. I can reach 300-350 meters with a stable communication (1 data send every 5 seconds). I was only able to, only one time, receive a data from a 1.4 km distance, but the message was corrupt, like this:

[image]

I have tried:

- Different programs and libraries (Now, i'm working with [this library](https://github.com/sandeepmistry/arduino-LoRa/blob/master/examples/LoRaReceiver/LoRaReceiver.ino))
- Frequencies from 410 MHz to 525 MHz, according to the range inscriptions on the module

But the distance is still far away from 1 km for a stable communication. I have seen some people reaching 2-3 km with this module and some documents say that it is possible to reach 10 km.

The question is, what am I doing wrong or what I should change to improve the results?

Any help or related experience is very useful!

Comment: how are the radios powered?

Comment: more over with what @jsotola asked, are you sure the voltage is not dropping when it transmits?

Comment: Rather than using that stubby antenna, which is compact but non-directional, you might consider a gain antenna (i.e. a directional one) instead.

Comment: If you haven't already, you should probably [make use of `setTxPower`](https://github.com/sandeepmistry/arduino-LoRa/blob/master/API.md#tx-power).  I doubt it will make *the* difference you're looking for, but it won't hurt.  The selectable bandwidth might also have an effect on range.

Comment: @chad-g The voltage is not dropping, also I have tried with a difference source of power and it works ok.

Comment: I think it could be something related with the antenna, as @jwh20 commented, but i should try first

Comment: @timemage thanks, I will try it